# How could I find the air velocity and lift force?

Tags: lift, airfoil

As shown below I have this information as shown below in the picture. I got the density according to the ISA standard  = 1.225[kg/m^3]  and  =  (−0) is calculated as below :

α=−4: CL=0

α=16: CL=0.025∗(16+4)=0.5 according to the diagram below:

I just want to know how to find the velocity and lift force?.

The lift force law is like this =(1/2)  ^2

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The indicated airspeed is the result of computation using basically the static pressure from the static pitot and the dynamic pressure from the dynamic pitot.
Further to apply your formula in addition to CL and the density, you need to know the active area S of the wings which at high speeds may depend on the speed itself, so you need the wings specific data.

Comment: So, wing surface is not the same of s in the equation?.

Comment: It is, but up till a speed limit

Comment: I got it. Thank you so much sir